# JavaScript Button input and output reset

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working with a button and a text label in javascript and HTML. I have a code that clears the input text label, but i also need the same button to clear the output message it gives = "helloNameOP". How would I add the 2 in the same function? I have both my codes listed below, that work perfectly separated, but I cant figure out how to put them together to work  simultaneously.

What I have tried:

```
 //for removing the Input text label:
onclick = document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value="";


//for removing the Output message recieved:
inputField = document.getElementById("helloNameOP")
document.getElementById('helloNameOP').textContent = " "
```

I'm not a javascript person, more of a kotlin gal, so I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’m understanding correctly, you can get a reference to the button, and then add an event listener.

```js
document.getElementById("the-button-id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value = "";
  document.getElementById("helloNameOP").textContent = "";
});
```